# Custom C# compiler warnings

Tags: c#

If I try to perform an implicit conversion from double to int I get
* a warning in the editor
* a compilation error

[image]

How can I implement this behavior for operators of custom types?

```
public struct A
{
    private readonly double value;

    public A(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // NOTE I want this operation to be prohibited
    public static A operator +(A a, B b)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public static implicit operator double(A a)
    {
        return a.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator A(double value)
    {
        return new A(value);
    }
}

public struct B
{
    private readonly double value;

    public B(double value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator double(B b)
    {
        return b.value;
    }

    public static implicit operator B(double value)
    {
        return new B(value);
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public void Method()
    {
        A a = 0.0d;
        B b = 0.0d;

        // QUESTION is there any way to show custom editor errors and/or make compilation fail?
        A result = a + b;
    }
}
```

As you can read in the example, I throw an exception if value types A and B are operands of an addition.

I'd like to show editor warnings and/or make the compilation fail. Is there any way to implement this behavior?

Comment: It is very simple. You cannot cast implicitly a type double to a type int. You need to use int y = Convert.ToInt32(x). Please try to pass the actual code next time and not an image.

Comment: This behavior is what happens when you have defined an explicit conversion operator and attempt to implicitly convert, custom type or not.

Comment: ...that behaviour is the default.  If you don't explicitly define a cast for a custom class, you cannot cast it to any other class (barring polymorphism of course)

Comment: I'm not interested in converting double to int. I have two custom types and I want to warn the developer that certain operators are not allowed when the operands are of the above mentioned two custom types.

Comment: `...and I want to warn the developer that certain operators are not allowed` <= By default it is already not allowed **unless you explicitly define them on the type(s)**. Not sure what you mean by warn them...

Comment: Try making an explicit conversion operator (Felix K's answer) that's what I was gonna suggest too.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer (I hope)

Comment: If you want addition and subtraction you can define those specific operators. If you don't want any other operators to be legal, then don't define them.

Comment: @ChrisRollins the two custom types are structs backed by two doubles and the compiler uses their operator overloads

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. The compiler will only allow the operators that you have defined.

Comment: If you are still having a problem then please add an [mcve] so we do not have to guess at the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I am confused by the question. The compiler already gives you warnings or errors if you do an implicit conversion that is not allowed between *any* two types, including the types you wrote. What are you really asking here?

Comment: @Eric Lippert, the error produced when two types have NO allowable conversion only shows the first part of the message he highlighted.  He wants both parts.

Comment: @Igor code added

Comment: @RichardII, thanks.

Comment: Is the question "how do I make a Roslyn Analyzer?" See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2017 for some helpful links.

Comment: `// QUESTION is there any way to show custom editor errors and/or make compilation fail?` <= I am not following, if you want this all you have to do is **not** define the `+` operator that you added in your code below `I want this operation to be prohibited`

Comment: @Igor try yourself

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks.

Comment: I did, see [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WIHsaC). The result is a compiler error "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'A' and 'B'"

Comment: @Igor, thanks. I don't know why I can't get both editor warnings and compiler errors in Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac. I'm going to investigate. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I get editor warnings in VS Community 2017 in this exact situation, but I'm on windows.

Comment: Wait, is this question "why does the mac version of visual studio have a bad UI for showing warnings?" I still don't understand what this question is asking.

Answer (score 5):

That's the default behavior of the compiler if there is no conversion and you do not need to do anything.

But to do the conversion you need to overload operators ( sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) ).

```
public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit fahr)
{
    return new Celsius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahr.Degrees - 32));
}
```

There are also other operators which you can overload ( Sample from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/operator) ):

```
public static Fraction operator +(Fraction a, Fraction b)
{
    return new Fraction(a.num * b.den + b.num * a.den,
       a.den * b.den);
}
```

Comment: The explicit (pun intended) answer to OP's question is that to get the desired behavior, you must define your conversion operator method with the "explicit operator" keywords.     Note that you should consider throwing (or allowing) an exception if data is lost in the conversion.  See this link for another example:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/using-conversion-operators

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to show custom editor errors and/or make compilation fail?

If you want this all you have to do is not define the `+` operator that you added in your code below "I want this operation to be prohibited".

See also [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WIHsaC).

Comment: I added the implicit operators from struct to double to both custom types and the warning disappears. I edited the question and the fiddle.